# BSON::InvalidDocument when inserting into MongoDB from iOS client

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, asihttprequest

I'm creating a basic blog app with rails/mongoid backend and an iOS client that has a posts model with name and image. I'm getting the following error when I create a new pos from an iOS app.

```
  BSON::InvalidDocument 
(Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON.):
      app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:47:in `create'
      app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

On the iOS side I'm using ASIHttpRequest with the following code:

```
 NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"[post] name"];
    [request setFile:@"/Users/Seb/Desktop/beach.jpeg" forKey:@"[post] image"]; 
    [request startSynchronous];
```

The server log shows:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu May 05 14:37:10 -0700 2011
  Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"post"=>{" name"=>"Ben", " image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x103e48fc8 @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="beach.jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"[post] image\"; filename=\"beach.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/PI/PI+kcHrCHfuDh-K+ppxAxE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110505-11613-x75qie-0>>}}
Completed   in 21ms

BSON::InvalidDocument (Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON.):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:47:in `create'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:46:in `create'

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.3ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (9.5ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the following class cannot be serialized into BSON: `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`.

Based on your post in the server logs, you're shipping up a JSON object with an unusual "image" field. I suspect the problem lies here.

It looks like your files is being stored to a temp location on the drive. Are you trying to save the actual bytes of the file or just this temp location? Are you using GridFs here?

Can you confirm that the class can indeed be serialized to BSON?
Is that serialization doing the right thing?

Comment: It should save the actual image in the images folder of my rails app. I'm not storing the image in Mongo, just the address of the image. I'm basically submitting a for to create a new post following the directions for ASIFormDataRequest

Comment: I was getting this issue through a typo in my form input name "imamge" instead of "image". Tsk tsk.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite obvious, and unless you want to use [paperclip](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip) or other solution, you'll have to do it yourself.

For example, if you happend to have a field :blob and field :filename in your model, then for saving you'll need to have something like this in your model:

```
class Post
...
  def image=(img)
    self.filename = img.original_filename
    self.blob = img.read
  end
end
```